# Why does the rotational level spacing increase when moment of inertia decrease?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, moment-of-inertia, vibrations

In the rigid rotor approach we obtain the result that the spacing between different rotational energy levels in a particular vibrational state is $\nu = 2B(J+1)$ and $ B = \frac{ h }{ 8 \pi^2 Ic }$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $c$ speed of light.

It seems counter intuitive to me why the energy levels would become closer spaced as we increase the moment of inertia of the molecule. I was expecting that a molecule with higher moment of inertia would require more energy to move from state to state and thus it would have bigger spacinng between levels. Why isn't that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, when considering a particular quantum state, increasing I means that the same amount of quantum angular momentum is distributed over a larger "space" (moment of inertia), thus lowering the energy state. In contrast, in the classical perspective, increasing
I while keeping angular velocity constant implies adding more kinetic energy due to the distribution of mass and the effort to maintain that rotational speed.

Answer (score 0):

You may expect that when $I$ is very large, then the energy(this terminology may not be so precise) of the molecule would reproduce the classical result. That is , the quantum characteristic would fade out.

Answer (score 0):

I will couch my answer in the study of diatomic molecules due to its simplicity. Given the total angular momentum quantum number is $J$ and the rotational constant $B$ is defined as in your formula, increasing the moment of inertia will decrease the rotational constant, and thus decrease the rotational energy of each individual state. For pure microwave spectroscopy of a rigid rotor with states $E_J = BJ(J+1)$ you would see a gap in the rotational states of $2B(J+1)$ as you said. This is nothing but pure mathematics. More intuitively, increasing the moment of inertia decreases the overall rotational energy of the molecule across all of its states. Because these states are all lower in energy and the gap between them is narrower, intuition suggests that moving between them should be easier, not more difficult. But this is a very quantum view since classically we would think of the object as "harder to get moving" when it has a higher inertia.

The associated IR spectroscopy problem is quite interesting, however, so I will include some discussion of the details here for completeness. The IR fundamental transitions $n=0\rightarrow n=1$) for a rigid rotor and a quantum harmonic oscillator model of a diatomic molecule give transitions separated by a fixed $2B$ for reasons I will explain below.

The main effect causing the transition spacing to differ is the difference in expectation values of the bond length in different vibrational states due to vibrational anharmonicity. The expectation values of the quantum harmonic oscillator (dashed, green levels and stars) are marked below alongside a Morse oscillator with modest anharmonicity (blue levels and dots).
[image: QHO_MPO]
Because the expected bond length increases, so too does the moment of inertia according to $I = \mu r^2$ where $\mu$ is the reduced mass. This effect can be modeled by adjusting the rotational energy formula to,
\begin{gather*}
E_J \approx BJ(J+1) - \alpha_e J(J+1) \left(n + \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{gather*}
where $\alpha_e$ is a small constant called the ro-vibrational coupling constant.

The P and R branches are the the $\Delta J = -1$ and $\Delta J = 1$ allowed transitions (for closed-shell molecules), where $J''$ is the rotational quantum number in the vibrational state $n=0$ and $J'$ is the rotational quantum number in the vibrational state $n=1$. This selection rule is due to the spin angular momentum of a photon being absorbed and requiring conservation of angular momentum for the whole system. This leads to transition energy formulas for the P and R branches for the vibrational fundamental ($n=0\rightarrow n=1$),
\begin{align*}
\nu_P &= \nu_{10} - (2B - 2\alpha_e)J'' - \alpha_e J''^2 \\
\nu_R &= \nu_{10} + (2b-3\alpha_3) - (2B - 4\alpha_e)J'' - \alpha_e J''^2 
\end{align*}
where $\nu_{10}$ is the vibrational fundamental. As you can see, these formulas will not give identically spaced energies for the various transitions due to the coupling constant $\alpha_e$, but give identically spaced transitions separated by $2B$ in the limit $\alpha_e \rightarrow 0$. But in any case even this problem depends directly on the moment of inertia of the molecule, and increasing it decreases the spacing.

Comment: I did not exactly understand the intuitive part of your explanation. You mentioned that by increasing moment of inertia the energy would decrease. Isn’t $E = 1/2 I \omega^2$? So why would energy decrease ? I am just getting started into this world so excuse me if I am missing something and thank you for the help.

Comment: The energy formula is generally written as $E_J=\frac{\hbar^2 J(J+1)}{2I}$ in quantum mechanics, exactly as we discussed. Your formula only works for a classical (Lagrangian) picture, whereas this formula is the quantum Hamiltonian perspective. Clearly, increasing I must decrease the energy in this case.